# how to disable auto login in linux mint

Tags: linux-mint, login-manager

I'm using linux mint with Cinnamon. The login screen comes to type a username but it also displays that in 10 seconds userx will be automatically logged in.

And it happens.

How to make it wait indefinitely?

Comment: Running Gnome Display Manager? (GDM)

Comment: Mint uses MDM a new Display Manager, which code is based on GDM 2.20.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Edit

```
/etc/mdm/mdm.conf
```

and set

```
AutomaticLoginEnable=false
```

Comment: after restart works great! I was able to remove `timedlogin` from the same file.

Comment: Not sure what version of Mint this applies, presumably 13.x or earlier; the file doesn't exist in my install of Mint 18.3. Other answers to this question seem to work better for newer versions of Mint.

Comment: For newer versions: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/179950/253746

Answer (score 8):

Open 'Menu' > 'Login Window' to open the Login Window Preferences.
Select the 'Security' tab > uncheck the 'Enable Automatic Login' option.

Comment: This worked for 17 (Rosa)

Comment: In Mint 19 (Tessa), I needed to remove the username from "Automatic login". Now, if I suspend, upon waking I do not require a password. Am I supposed to lock the screen before suspending?

Answer (score 5):

That was not enough. For some weird reason Mint added a user by default to the `nopasswdlogin` group and no mater how long you play with the settings above, that user will not be challenged for a password.

Solution: Go to **Menu > Administration > Users and Groups** and remove that user from the `nowpasswdlogin` group.

Comment: thanks! this was the only thing that worked for me today.

Answer (score 4):

To me, disabling "Enable Automatic Login" in "Auto Login" tab from Login Window Preferences wasn't enough (login screen was showing up, but a moment later system was automatic logging me). 
I had to uncheck also "Enable Timed Login" from the same section.

Answer (score 1):

In Mint 17/18 you need to go to `Users and Groups`, select the user in question from the menu on the left, then next to "Password" on the right, click "Change..." and make sure "Don't ask for password on login" is unchecked.

Comment: after restart the problem appears again. It does not fix.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. Open the file

```
sudo xed /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

and remove the following lines

```
autologin-user=<user>
autologin-user-timeout=0
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Needed to remove autoboot to fix the keyring issue. Everything worked as it should on restart. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Mint 16 Petra you need to turn on time delay for *nopasswlogin* user.

Comment: Can you show an example of how this should be done?

Answer (score -2):

In linux Mint 20.2 (Cinnamon 5) you need to type in your terminal:

$ sudo xed /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf

autologin-user=false

Must be "false"

Comment: I wonder whether that means that it should try to automatically login a user named `false`, and that it fails (silently?) if there is no such user. [antikbd already suggested](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/668571/80216) deleting the `autologin-user=` line altogether. Do you believe that your answer is better? Why?

Comment: This could only possibly affect a GUI login. In fact, you need to do more than this - see other answers.