# how to disable auto login in Linux Mint 19 Cinnamon

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, login-manager

I would like to disable the auto-logon feature on my Linux Mint 19 Cinnamon box.

I have tried all the answers to [This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45573/how-to-disable-auto-login-in-linux-mint) question (same question, older Mint)

None have worked.

How do you disable auto-login on Mint 19 Cinnamon?

Thanks a bunch!

[Edit] seems like questions about this is frowned upon.
Thanks @inquisitive_lurker and @Andrew F for pointing me in the right direction

[Edit 2] Famous Question, 10.000 views and 2 downvotes :-)

Comment: This seems like the inverse of [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/381785/how-do-i-enable-auto-login-in-mint-18) answer. You may want to try something along those lines.

Comment: Specifically, see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/473602/229687) to the question Andrew linked.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @Andrew F and @Inquisitive Lurker

This is how you do it on Cinnamon 19:

1. Menu
2. Preferences
3. System Settings
4. Login Window ( + enter credentials)
5. [Users] tab

Under ["Automatic login": username*] -> Remove entered login

Close window (there is no "save")

Reboot

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it on Cinnamon 19.1:

Menu

Administration

Login Window ( + enter credentials)

[Users] tab

Under ["Automatic login": username*] -> Remove entered login

Close window (there is no "save")

Reboot